# Request Capture{model: PaymentDetails} is not supported:Sofort

Tags: zend-framework, payment, capture, payum

I am trying to integrate the Sofort Payum module in zend framework 2 but all i got this error i have controller method as follows:

```
public function sofortAction()
{
    $storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum')->getStorage('Reisesparer\Model\PaymentDetails');

    $details                = $storage->create();
    $details['currency']    = 'USD';
    $details['amount']      = 100;

    $storage->update($details);

    $captureToken = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
        'sofort', $details, 'payment_done'
    );

    $this->redirect()->toUrl($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
}
```

And my model has the following piece of code extend the ArratObject:

```
namespace Reisesparer\Model;

use Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject;


class PaymentDetails extends  ArrayObject
{
}
```

I got the error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\payum\payum\src\Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException.php:29
Request Capture{model: PaymentDetails} is not supported.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\payum\payum\src\Payum\Core\Gateway.php(99): Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException::create(Object(Payum\Core\Request\Capture))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\payum\payum\src\Payum\Core\Action\ExecuteSameRequestWithModelDetailsAction.php(32): Payum\Core\Gateway->execute(Object(Payum\Core\Request\Capture))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\payum\payum\src\Payum\Core\Gateway.php(107): Payum\Core\Action\ExecuteSameRequestWithModelDetailsAction->execute(Object(Payum\Core\Request\Capture))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\payum\payum-module\src\Payum\PayumModule\Controller\CaptureController.php(19): Payum\Core\Gateway->execute(Object(Payum\Core\Request\Capture))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Payum\PayumModule\Controller\CaptureController->doAction()
#5 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendreisen\reisesparer\public\index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

But the paypal module is work fine with the same model how could i fix this issue and make the sofort work in zf2.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the rest of your error stacktrace?

Comment: I have updated the question with Error message can you please have a look? @Dymen1

Comment: This stacktrace doesn't mention the `sofortAction` you included

Comment: I think all the capture method are defined in Payum\Core\Request\Capture

Comment: Without the code containing the configuration the use of PaymentDetails, I can't really help you

Comment: What file code you want to see i will post here.?